# How do I handle returning an async task nullable object

Tags: c#

I'm using .Net 7.

I have a method declared as:

```
public async Task<Product[]?> GetProducts(Dictionary<string, dynamic> keyValuePairs)
```

and I'm calling a 3rd party APi that will return me an object in the form:

```
public class ProductResponse
{
    public Product[]? Results { get; set; }
    public int Item_Count { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

From the response, I'm only interested in the Product array. The APi may return this back as null.

In my `GetProducts` method I attempt to return the products in the following way:

```
return await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs).Result?.Results;
```

This red Lines straight away with:

> 'Product[]' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no
> accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Product[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

Can anybody suggest how I should be returning this?

Comment: `return (await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs)).Results;`?In your current code, you're trying to `await` the `Results` property of your object, not the method call.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you this has removed the red line and now placed it as a green line with `Dereference of a possibly null reference`

Comment: @DanielMann this did it `return (await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs))?.Results;` If you would like to change your comment to an answer I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this line of yours

```
await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs).Result?.Results;
```

You've got the `await` keyword. What does that operate on? Well, everything to the right, that means all of this:

```
_httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs).Result?.Results
```

`GetRequest`<sup>1</sup> returns a `Task`, but the two Result(s) at the end don't. Whatever is the last symbol to the right of the `await` (in the same scope) needs to return a Task. A shorter example:

```
// psudo code to explain your line
await client.GetDataAsync().WaitAndReturnData.PropertyOfObject;
//           ^ Task<Custom class>
//                          ^ Custom class
//                                            ^ Property
```

How do you fix this? You need to await the right thing, which is *only* the `GetRequest` method call.

```
// multiple lines (I prefer this as it's easier for me to read)
var response = await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs);
var results = response?.Results;

// single line
var results = (await _httpClientService.GetRequest<ProductResponse>(url, _headerPairs))?.Results;
```

The key with the "single line" option is that the `await` and the method call are wrapped in parentheses, and you access the `Results` property after the await has concluded.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a reason why nearly every Microsoft made method that returns a Task has a suffix of "Async" - it's easy to recognize that it returns a Task, and therefore clear what exactly needs to be awaited. This is opinion and you don't need to follow it, but I'd recommend using the Async suffix if you can. However, this could be the Hungarian Notation argument all over again.